# AWS Crawler for All Subfolders of a Specific name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm working on creating 2 crawlers for some data sets in AWS.  The issue I'm currently running into is this.  I have a folder structure that resembles something like this:

```
bucket/client1/project1/source1/file1.txt
bucket/client1/project1/source2/file1.txt
bucket/client2/project1/source1/file1.txt
bucket/client2/project1/source2/file1.txt
etc..
```

The issue I'm hitting is that I know for all my source2 data I'm going to need to add a custom classifier that manually spells out all the header information.  Reason being is that the file rows all come back as strings with no clear way to tell the header from the body of the file.  So, my solution was to create a crawler that would only crawl the source2 folders, regardless of client or projects, and use a custom classifier.  When specifying the endpoint for the crawler I'm trying to use wildcards so it will only crawl the source2 folders regardless of client or project name.  I've tried endpoints like:

```
bucket/*/*/source2/
bucket/*/*/source2
bucket/**/**/source2
bucket/**/source2
```

Each time I keep getting an error on the crawler stating that it cannot for the specified S3 endpoint.

Is doing this even possible using wildcard characters in the endpoint string, and if so what should the formatting look like to make it work?

Comment: Crawlers tend to work over specific buckets or bucket prefixes. To help my understanding, is the problem for you that the crawler output (where part of the path is source2) is incorrect?

Comment: No the problem is I want to crawl over all subfolders of a certain name, in the example source2, regardless of the folder structure above it.  So for the bucket, crawl all subfolders named source2 for all clients and all projects essentially.

Comment: And I'm guessing it doesn't necessarily make sense to reorder the prefixes so that source1/source2 is at the start as that would solve this very easily?

Comment: Correct for management and schema purposes it's broken out this way.